# How to make a good search with sql and php?

Tags: php, sql, function, search

How do I make a good search with sql and php by three tables with multiple search words? And how to give it back on the screen?

I work in a framework which is homemade at my internship. The following I have fabricated myself only this not completely correct I think.

I have te following think all ready:

```
function find_by_all($search) {
$searchwords = explode(" ", $search);

foreach ($searchwords as $word) {
    if ($word === end($searchwords)) {
        $query_where .= "companies.companyname LIKE  '%" . $word . "%' OR companies.city LIKE  '%" . $word . "%' OR persons.firstname LIKE  '%" . $word . "%' OR persons.lastname LIKE  '%" . $word . "%' OR investments.name LIKE  '%" . $word . "%' OR investments.firstname LIKE  '%" . $word . "%' OR investments.lastname LIKE  '%" . $word . "%'";
    } else {
        $query_where .= "companies.companyname LIKE  '%" . $word . "%' OR companies.city LIKE  '%" . $word . "%' OR persons.firstname LIKE  '%" . $word . "%' OR persons.lastname LIKE  '%" . $word . "%' OR investments.name LIKE  '%" . $word . "%' OR investments.firstname LIKE  '%" . $word . "%' OR investments.lastname LIKE  '%" . $word . "%' AND ";
     }
}

return $this->find_by_sql("SELECT * FROM companies LEFT JOIN investings ON investings.investing_id = companies.company_id LEFT JOIN investments ON investments.investment_id = companies.company_id LEFT JOIN persons ON persons.person_id = companies.company_id WHERE ".$query_where);
```

Now I think this is reasonably well, only this SQL and result I also need to get see on my screen, only I do not know how to do this. Can anyone help me?

Comment: Try `full text search`.

Comment: First, I normally assume that people want their search words in order, so I do something like $query_where = "companies.companyname like '%".str_replace(' ','%',$search)."%'"; Other than that, what does find_by_sql return? A result? An array? A text list?

Comment: @kainaw the find_by_sql function returns an array that I put in a foreach. With the foreach I will put the results in a <li> and echo the results.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I made it and it is no longer needed to help me now. I have made three separate queries ​​for the searchfunction and now he do it.